What does "They" in "They're gone" refer to?
After activating the Super-Collider, Kingpin ignores Spider-Man’s concerns
about the potential danger it could cause, such as creating a black hole under Brooklyn.
He implies that his motivations are not solely about money, suggesting deeper reasons
behind his actions. All this while, Peter Miles is observing from a distance, concealed
within the rubble. Prowler approaches with an intent to kill Spider-Man, but Kingpin
intervenes to stop him:

Kingpin: Wait.
Spider-Man: I know what you're trying to do......and it won't work.
They're gone.

Kingpin looks furious and delivers the killing blow himself.
What does "They" in "They're gone" refer to?

Kingpin is trying to replace his dead wife Vanessa and son Richard with copies from somewhere in the multiverse.
Spider-Man is trying to stop the collider from opening the multiverse and causing untold havoc by telling Fisk that "they" (Vanessa and Richard) are gone.
